# Accessing an object attribute in an event function

Tags: python

I've been trying to use `def on_mouse_click` to change a value from another object. I'm using pyglet to make a game. It looks like this:

```
import random, math, time
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *
window = pyglet.window.Window(640, 480, visible=False, caption="Pong")
window.set_location(window.screen.width/2 - window.width/2, window.screen.height/2 - window.height/2)
batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()

class Ball(pyglet.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pattern = pyglet.image.SolidColorImagePattern((139, 90, 43, 120))

        image = pyglet.image.create(8,8,pattern)
        image.anchor_x, image.anchor_y = 20, 0

        pyglet.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, image, batch=batch)

    def reset(self):
        self.x, self.y = 0 ,0
        angle = random.random()*math.pi/2
        self.vx, self.vy = math.sin(angle)*300, math.cos(angle)*300

@window.event        
def on_resize(width, height):
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height)

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glOrtho(0, 800, 0, 600, -1, 1)
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()
    return pyglet.event.EVENT_HANDLED

keymap = pyglet.window.key.KeyStateHandler()
window.push_handlers(keymap)
states = []

class PausedState:
    def update(self, dt):
        if keymap[pyglet.window.key.SPACE]:
            states.pop()

class GameState:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = Ball()
        self.b.reset()
    def update(self, dt):
        @window.event
        def on_mouse_press(x, y, button, modifiers):
            self.b.angle = 0
        self.b.x += self.b.vx *dt
        self.b.y += self.b.vy *dt

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()

    batch.draw()

def update(dt): 
    if len(states):
        states[-1].update(dt)
    else:
        pyglet.app.exit()

states.append(GameState())
states.append(PausedState())

pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(update, 1.0/60.0)

window.clear()
window.flip()
window.set_visible(True)

pyglet.app.run()
```

I'm getting an error that says `global 'self is not defined'`. I'm expecting to change the angle of the ball by clicking the left mouse button. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: It would be helpful if you include trackback of your error ?

Comment: Also, could you review the indentation? Is `on_mouse_press` nested inside `GameState.update`? You should provide a [*working minimal example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, sorry. I've edited it already. I'm kind of having a difficulty putting the whole code in because i've already gone far. I'm pretty sure what I've put says what i mean.

Comment: As it stands, the code you have posted cannot be run by others to recreate the error. The indentation is still not correct, and the definition of `class GameState` is missing. You should cut your code down to the smallest sample that recreates the error - this is a crucial part of finding and fixing bugs.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Made a working code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to declare a setter method like follow ? :

```
#in your class
def setB(new_b):
  self.b = new_b
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Is that on class ball or Class Gamestate? I had an error trying to implement yours on the code.

Comment: Python doesn't need getters and setters - you have access to attributes by default, and a `@property` is the Pythonic way to protect attribute access where required.

Comment: @jonrsharpe the setter method worked! Thanks Captain Totem! :)